# Homework help: prime numbers

Tags: c++, list, primes

I'm trying to make an bool Isprime function that creates a list of prime numbers covering a user-input integer, then linearly search through that list and return true if the input integer is in that list. I'm having a problem, however, figuring out how to make the list that covers the input integer (that is, if the user inputs 4, the list must have 2,3, and 5).

Here is the code I have so far (I know it's completely wrong, I've tried doing research but I just can't figure out how to do this.

```
bool Isprime(int N){
  int i,tprime=3;
  list<int>prime;
  prime.push_back(2);
  list<int>::iterator it;
    for (it=prime.begin();it!=prime.end();it++){
      if (*it<N){
        while (i<sqrt(tprime)){
          if(N%i!=0){
            if(i<sqrt(tprime))
              i++;
            else prime.push_back(tprime);
          }
        tprime++;
        }
      }
    }
  for (it=prime.begin();it!=prime.end();it++){
    if (*it==N)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Can you guys give me some hints on how to make this work? I can figure out the linear search.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Show your _real_ code.

Comment: "that creates a list of prime numbers covering a user-input integer" <-- I'm not sure I get that. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: @not-rightfold that is the code I have, except for the linear search. What is the syntax error?

Comment: @Hippo, for instance, if the user input 8, the list would have to contain 2,3,5,7, and 11. the list has to contain prime numbers up to the one equal or greater than the input integer.

Comment: @JakeHafendorfer You are missing `::` between `<int>` and `iterator`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that when typing the code to the question. It's in my actual code. Edited.

Comment: Do you really need to create that list of primes? That function would be way simpler and faster without it.

Comment: Yes I do, and I know. It bothers me too.

Answer (score 0):

You got a list of known primes which you can use to check each individual number to see if it a prime. Right now you try to iterate over this list on the outer level. That doesn't seem to be quite right.

Here is one way to go about it (matching what you tried to do):

1. Count from 3 up to the number you are looking for.
2. Determine the maximum prime value you need to check against (i.e., the square root of the number)
3. For each number check if it is a prime number by determining the reminder of dividing it to each element of the known primes list up to the maximum value you need to check.
4. If the number is a prime, add it to the list of known primes.

Comment: The maximum prime value I need to check against has to be equal or greater to the input integer, not the square root. How to I make that happen without iterating through the list?

Comment: My point is that you can stop processing primes from the list of known primes when checking a specific number once you encountered a prime which is bigger than the square root of the value currently being checked. Since computing the square root is a fairly expensive operation you'd want to do it once for each number you want to check for being a prime. With respect to your question: I think I gave you quite precise instructions. You mean me to write the code? Well, you see, I don't need these exercises anymore.